# Prove: the set of continuous functions $C[0,1]$ is not closed in a set of all bounded functions with finitely many points of discontinuity $B_f[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

$\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is a norm on $B_f[0,1]$. I was able to prove that $C[0,1]\subseteq B_f[0,1]$, Picking a convergent sequence in $C[0,1]$ with the limit, say $g\in B_f[0,1]$. I wanted to show that $ g$ could not belong to $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Which norm is exactly $\|\cdot\|_{2}$?

Comment: It is the $\ell_2$ norm.

Comment: $B_f[0,1]$ is a subspace of $L^2(0,1).$ The subspace $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2(0,1),$ Hence every function in $B_f[0,1]$ can be approximated in $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm by continuous functions.

Comment: What's the conclusion here? I don't follow.

Comment: How does this prove that $C[0,1]$ is not closed in $B_f[0,1]$?

Comment: Take a function $f(x)=0$ for $0\le x< {1/2}$ and $f(x)=1$ for $1/2\le x\le 1.$ Let $f_n$ be defined by $f_n(x)=0$ for $0\le x\le 1/2-1/n,$ $f_n(x)=1$ for $1/2\le x\le 1$ and $f_n(x)$ is linear between the points $1/2 -1/n$ and $1/2..$ Then $f_n$ are continuous and  $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm. But $f$ is discontinuous.